# Slice a row containing time range into multiple rows (tricky sql question)

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, split

First of all, I was unable to specify the title to contain my entire problem. My apologies.

My goal is to multiply rows while changing some column values until a certain criterion is met. Yes, awful explanation.

I have:

```
CREATE TABLE OldTable 
(
    fullname varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    unit varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    code int NOT NULL,
    shift_datetime datetime NOT NULL,
    timespan int NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO OldTable (fullname, unit, code, shift_datetime, timespan) 
VALUES ('John Smith', 'Heroes', '239', '2020-03-04 13:35:00.000', '55'
'Tom Cruise', 'Heroes', '213', '2020-03-05 09:13:00.000', '8'
'My Mom', 'Heroes', '483', '2020-02-01 08:57:00.000', '16')
```

yields this table, `OldTable`:

```
| fullname   | unit   | code | shift_datetime          | timespan |
+------------+--------+------+-------------------------+----------+
| John Smith | Heroes | 239  | 2020-03-04 13:35:00.000 |      55  |
| Tom Cruise | Heroes | 213  | 2020-03-05 09:13:00.000 |       8  |
| Mom        | Heroes | 483  | 2020-02-01 08:57:00.000 |      16  |
```

I would like to create this `NewTable`:

```
| fullname   | unit   | code | shift_datetime          | timespan |
+------------+--------+------+-------------------------+----------+
| John Smith | Heroes | 239  | 2020-03-04 13:35:00.000 |      15  |
| John Smith | Heroes | 239  | 2020-03-04 13:50:00.000 |      15  |
| John Smith | Heroes | 239  | 2020-03-04 14:05:00.000 |      15  |
| John Smith | Heroes | 239  | 2020-03-04 14:20:00.000 |      10  |
| Tom Cruise | Heroes | 213  | 2020-03-05 09:13:00.000 |       8  |
| Mom        | Heroes | 483  | 2020-02-01 08:57:00.000 |      15  |
| Mom        | Heroes | 483  | 2020-02-01 08:12:00.000 |       1  |
```

So the problem formulation is rather

`if span > 15`, then divide into `floor(span/15)` rows with `span = 15` in each row while increasing `shift_datetime` by 15 miutes for each added row, finally adding the last row where `span = span %% 15` and add those `span %% 15` minutes to the largest `shift_datetime` value in that "loop".

If you have any ideas how to 'attack' this problem, I'd appreciate it. I'm not *only* looking for a solution, but I'm very much looking for advice on how to deal with such issue.

I am able to do this in R through a loop so I'm assuming this can be done by a loop in SQL as well. I would, however, love to hear about other options or ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a recursive CTE can help:

```
with cte as (
      select fullname, unit, code, shift_datetime, 
             (case when timespan > 15 then 15 else timespan end) as timespan,
             timespan as time_remaining, 1 as lev
      from oldtable
      union all
      select fullname, unit, code,
             dateadd(minute, 15, shift_datetime),
             (case when time_remaining > 15 then 15 else time_remaining end) as timespan,
             time_remaining - 15, lev + 1
      from cte
      where time_remaining > 15
     )
select * 
from cte
order by 1, lev;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1337569eff43d48015829e22b4f550af) is a db<>fiddle.